DQN Agent for Tic-Tac-Toe Performance Plateau: Loss Not Decreasing and Win Rate Stuck at 75%
I'm implementing a Deep Q-Network (DQN) agent for Tic-Tac-Toe where the DQN agent always plays as player 2 (O), and it competes against a hardcoded opponent (player 1, X) with a variable "smartness" level. The smartness parameter ranges from 0 to 1, where at 0 the opponent plays completely randomly, and at 1 it tries to win or block the player when possible.
Here are the key details of my DQN setup:

Replay Buffer: Size 5000, from which it samples in batches.
Model Update: Updates the model every 100 episodes.
Learning Rate: 0.0005
Soft-Q Learning: Implemented with a temperature parameter (tau).
Discount Factor (gamma): 0.99
Temperature Decay (tau): Starting at 0.8, decays by 0.99.
Batch Size: 32
Target Network Update: Updates after every 4 batches to stabilize learning.
The architecture for the DQN uses one-hot encoding with layer sizes of 27-128-64-9 (two hidden layers).
win reward:+1,loss reward:-1 and draw reward:-0.5
Player Representations: Hardcoded opponent is represented by -1; DQN agent is represented by +1.

Problem:

After around 3500 games, the loss function stops decreasing, and the agent's performance plateaus at an average reward of about 0.5.
The win rate stays around 75% but doesn’t increase further and becomes worse with increasing opponent’s smartness level. At 0.5 smartness win rate decreases to 50%
Changing the smartness level of the opponent seems to amplify this issue, leading to unstable training and inconsistent performance.
I even trained upto 26,000 games with the same logic, except I increase smartness level by 0.1 whenever win rate becomes 75 percent, but it fails after reaching smartness of 0.5.

Question: What could be causing the agent's performance to plateau, and why might the loss function not be decreasing despite a stable learning rate, gamma, and tau decay? Are there any adjustments to the architecture, training loop, or hyperparameters that might help improve the agent's learning and achieve a higher win rate?
I have attached a snippet of the code I used down below and a graph of the loss function and total rewards over 100 episodes.
    def one_hot_encode(self,state):
        new_state=np.zeros((9,3))
        for i,j in enumerate(state):
            if j==1:
                new_state[i][0]=0
                new_state[i][1]=0
                new_state[i][2]=1
            elif j==-1:
                new_state[i][0]=0
                new_state[i][1]=1
                new_state[i][2]=0
            else:
                new_state[i][0]=1
                new_state[i][1]=0
                new_state[i][2]=0
        return np.array(new_state).reshape(1,27)
    
    def action(self,game):
        valid_actions = [i for i, spot in enumerate(game.board) if spot == 0]
        state = self.one_hot_encode(game.board)

        # Predict Q-values and apply softmax to choose action
        q_values = self.model.predict(state, verbose=0)[0]
        #get valid q values
        q_valid=[spot for i,spot in enumerate(q_values) if i in valid_actions]
    
        probabilities = softmax(q_valid, tau=self.tau)
        position = valid_actions[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(probabilities)), p=probabilities)]
        return position

    def remember(self,state_representation):
        self.memory.append(state_representation)
    
    def replay(self, player_turn):
        num_batches = len(self.experience) // self.batch_size
        with tqdm(range(num_batches), desc="Replay Progress", unit="batch", dynamic_ncols=True) as replay_bar:
            for e in replay_bar:
                mini_batch = random.sample(self.experience, self.batch_size)
                states = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 27))
                q_values = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 9))

                for i, (state, action, reward, next_state, done) in enumerate(mini_batch):

                    state = self.one_hot_encode(state)
                    next_state = self.one_hot_encode(next_state)

                    # Soft Q-value update
                    if done:
                        q_target = reward
                    else:
                        next_q_values = self.target_model.predict(next_state, verbose=0)[0]
                        softmax_probs = softmax(next_q_values, tau=self.tau)
                        q_target = reward + self.gamma * np.sum(softmax_probs * next_q_values)

                    q_value = self.target_model.predict(state, verbose=0)[0]
                    q_value[action] = q_target
                    states[i] = state
                    q_values[i] = q_value

                self.tau = max(self.tau * self.tau_decay, 0.1)
                # Fit the model without verbose output
                history = self.model.fit(states, q_values, epochs=1, verbose=0)
                loss = history.history['loss'][0]
                self.loss_history.append(loss)

                if e % 4 == 0:
                    self.target_model.set_weights(self.model.get_weights())
            
            # Final update of target model after all batches
            self.target_model.set_weights(self.model.get_weights())




